# Console.WriteLine does not work when attached to process in VS

Tags: visual-studio

If I have a code in C# .NET (winforms) which contains a `Console.WriteLine("TEST");` and visual studio is attached to the process it doesn't write "TEST" in the output window.
(application is correctly attached)

If I start my program normal with visual studio, it works.

**Why does it not work in the first case?**

Comment: `Console` is what? The JS browser console? The .Net Console? Some custom class? Are you trying to say that output sent to STDOUT is captured by VS when running a standalone app, but it is not captured when running in the context of a test framework? And what test framework are you using? XUnit, MSUnit, NUnit?

Comment: edited my question.

Comment: It is not a "normal" feature, a Winforms app does not have a console.  It only works thanks to the Visual Studio Hosting Process.  Which is an option, configured with Project > Properties > Debug tab.  Which is the key, it is missing when you attach to a process instead of pressing F5.  And will be missing in the future, it was discontinued for VS2017.  Use the Debug class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio, when debugging *windows* programs ([`/target:winexe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/target-winexe-compiler-option)) will launch them with the  `stdout` and `stderr` redirected to Named Pipes. The other end of the named pipe is owned by the VS debugger and anything read on these pipes (ie. anything written by the app to stdout or stderr) will be displayed in the **Debug** Output window (which by no means is the debugged application Output window).

When attach to an application, this redirect can no longer be done (obviously, since the application is already started and `stderr` and `stdin` cannot be redirected post-factum). So the `Console.Write` is no longer auto-magically redirected to the Debug output.

Note that this stdout/stderr redircetion does not occur for console programs ([`/target:exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/target-exe-compiler-option))

But there is a dedicated API to write Debug info: [`Debug.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.write(v=vs.110).aspx). This uses the [`OutputDebugString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx) functions, which sends text to the attached debugger (if any). This works no matter when or how the debugger is attached, as is not dependent upon stdout/stderr redirection tricks.

Replace your `Console.Write` with `Debug.Write`.

Comment: Thanks Remus. using Console = System.Diagnostics.Debug;